# Realloc issue: free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, realloc

I am trying to write a simple program that stores events in C, initially I allocate memory for one single event with `malloc()`(events are stored in an array of structs), each time I add a new event, from edit menu, I write event data in the previously allocated struct, then, using `realloc()`, allocate memory for the next event to be added.
**Here is my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct events{
    char name[50];
    //date:
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int budget;
}events;

void add_event(struct events *p, int i){
    printf("\n> Enter event details");
    printf("\n name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]%*c", p[i].name);
    printf(" Date (dd.mm.yyyy): ");
    scanf("%d.%d.%d", &p[i].day, &p[i].month, &p[i].year);
    printf(" Budget(USD): ");
    scanf("%d", &p[i].budget);
}

int edit_menu(struct events *p){
    static int qtty=0;
    struct events *tmp;
    int select;
    do{
        system("clear");
        printf("\n> Edit menu:\n 1) Add event\n 2) Delete event\n 0) Return\n-->");
        scanf("%d", &select);

        switch(select){
            case 1:{
                add_event(p, qtty);
                
                tmp=(struct events*)realloc(p, sizeof(struct events)*(qtty+1));
                qtty+=1;
                
                if(tmp!=NULL)
                    p=tmp;
                else
                    printf("\n Fail!");

                }break;
        }
    }while(select);

    return qtty;
}

void show_data(struct events *p, int i){
    printf("\n> %d) ", i);
    puts(p[i].name);
    printf("\n Date: %d.%d.%d", p[i].day, p[i].month, p[i].year);
    printf("\n Budget: %d USD", p[i].budget);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    int select, qtty=0;
    char search_input[50];
    struct events *p=malloc(sizeof(events));

    do{
        system("clear");
        printf("\n Event Menu:\n 1) Show all events[%d]\n 2) Search for event\n 3) Edit events\n 0) Quit\n-->", qtty);
        scanf("%d", &select);

        switch(select){
        case 1:
            for(int i=0; i<qtty; i++)
                show_data(p, i);
            sleep(3);
            break;
        case 2:{
            system("clear");
            printf("\n Enter event name: ");
            scanf("%[^\n]%*c", search_input);
            //srch_event(e, search_input);
            }break;
        case 3:{
            qtty=edit_menu(p);
            }
        }
    }while(select);

    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

My issue is that whenever I use `realloc()`, the name of the first "event" somehow gets corrupted, and the parameters of the second "event" are random long numbers.
The third call of `realloc()` crashes the program, giving me `free(): double free detected in tcache 2` error.

**Shortly said:** using `(struct events*)realloc(p, sizeof(struct events)*(qtty+1));` is not working out to resize my array of structs to a bigger size to store one more "event", and crushes the program.

Changing how I sent my pointer to the function did not help nor what size *realloc()* reallocates to. The issue seems to lay somewhere in this function:

```
int edit_menu(struct events *p){
    static int qtty=0;
    struct events *tmp;
    int select;
    do{
        system("clear");
        printf("\n> Edit menu:\n 1) Add event\n 2) Delete event\n 0) Return\n-->");
        scanf("%d", &select);

        switch(select){
            case 1:{
                add_event(p, qtty);
                
                tmp=(struct events*)realloc(p, sizeof(struct events)*(qtty+1));
                qtty+=1;
                
                if(tmp!=NULL)
                    p=tmp;
                else
                    printf("\n Fail!");

                }break;
        }
    }while(select);

    return qtty;
}
```

Or in main, where I use `malloc()`.

Comment: edit_menu is only updating its local copy of p, you need to pass `struct events **p`

Comment: If you want to be able to reallocate memory inside the function you'll need to pass a double pointer. Right now `p=tmp;` is assigning the new pointer to a copy of the one passed in from `main`.